# print characters repetitively using asterisk symbol in bash

Tags: printf

```
print '*' * 80
```

This python snippet prints 80 asterisks, which I use often as delimiters in log files.

How can I do it in bash script using operator overloading?

Comment: Is there *operator overloading* existing in `bash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In shell (`ksh`, `zsh`, `bash`) you can do:

```
stars=$(printf '%*s' 80 '')
echo "${stars// /*}"
```

With `bash` there's the option of doing:

```
printf -v stars '%*s' 80 ''
echo "${stars// /*}"
```

Explanation: The `printf` uses a format string `%*s` which means to produce a string of a length that is provided through an argument. So the first argument (`80`) specifies the length and the second argument specifies the string (`''`, an empty string) to be effectively printed, but blank-padded to the defined width. Note that this could also be expressed as `printf "%80s" ''`, though I used the parameterized version for the length to make it explicit that it can be a variable parameter.

Comment: `printf -v` will help avoid the need for a command substitution

Comment: For `bash` that's correct. - But note that `printf -v` is not widely available in shells thus less portable. In `ksh`, e.g., you don't have it, and in `ksh` you also don't have a reason to avoid this command substitution (no subshell process in this case). - So despite the OP's question restricted itself by its formulation to `bash` users of other shells may prefer a wider support of that code pattern.

Comment: hi janis, i understand for printf, `%*s` is a space char and 2nd argument is the character count. what does the last argument `''` mean?

Comment: @Madhavan Kumar; `%*s` is the format string, `80` and `''` are the arguments for `printf`; I added an explanation in my answer.